# Accessing netCDF variable value using xarray

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

```
hndl_nc['name_variable'][:, :, :, var]
```

I am opening a netCDF file using xarray and want to access a layer as given above. The shape of the netCDF file is `(25 * 360 * 720 * 5)`.

Is there a way to rewrite `hndl_nc['name_variable'][:, :, :, var]` so that I do not have to specify `:, :, :, var`? I want to make the variable access independent of the structure of netCDF if possible.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41797531/792066), I also want the soln to work in case of `hndl_nc['name_variable'][:, :, :, var]`

Comment: How's your **--EDIT** different than what you mention at the beginning, namely `hndl_nc['name_variable'][:, :, :, var]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you're using **xarray** ([xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/index.html)), I imagine you're doing something like the following:

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset(path_file)
```

You have a couple of options according to the documentation (http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html):

1. Dimension lookup by name, Index lookup by integer
2. Dimension lookup by name, Index lookup by label

**Dimension lookup by name, Index lookup by integer**

To index using an integer you can

```
ds['new_var'] = ds.isel(var=0)
```

or

```
ds['new_var'] = ds[dict(var=0)]
```

I'm assuming one of the dimension is called `var`. For the sake of simplicity I just chose the 1st element in `var`, so adapt to your need.
You can select a value or select a slice for `var`. Please, see more in the documentation I linked above.

**Dimension lookup by name, Index lookup by label**
To look inside one of the dimensions using a label, one could do:

```
ds['new_var'] = ds.sel(var='IA')
```

or

```
ds['new_var'] = ds.loc[dict(var='IA')]
```

I'm not sure it fits your case or this is what you're looking for, as I couldn't understand very well your case.

Answer (score 1):

The ellipsis `...` should work:

```
hndl_nc['name_variable'][..., var]
```

Comment: thanks @Mike, I should have been clearer. The ellipsis won't work in this case: `:, var, :, :`. Is there a soln for that?

Comment: You will increase the change to get a good answer if you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Like not: `VisibleDeprecationWarning: an index can only have a single Ellipsis (...); replace all but one with slices (:).`